# Insert spaces before and after special symbols in python

Tags: python, string

I want preprocess strings using Python.
Here is an example.

Given a string

```
string = "hello... (world)!"
```

I want to insert spaces before and after special characters like

```
desired_string = "hello . . . ( world ) !"
```

I find a way to do this by replace function.

```
string = string.replace(".", " . ")
string = string.replace("(", " ( ")
string = string.replace(")", " ) ")
string = string.replace("!", " ! ")
```

Then,

```
>>> string
'hello .  .  .   ( world )  ! '
```

(This output string has more spaces than desired_string but is acceptable because I well apply `.split` method later.)

But the code is lengthy especially when many types of symbols appear. (e.g. !, @, $, %, &, ....)

I think there is a better way (maybe using `re.sub` ?) Does anybody can show a better code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using `re` adds white-space before and after the desired characters:

```
import re

pat = re.compile(r"([.()!])")
print (pat.sub(" \\1 ", string))
# hello .  .  .   ( world )  !
```

Comment: Its for the first group which in this case would be `[.()!]`, you can have multiple groups like that in `()` parenthesis and use `\\1`, `\\2`, `\\3` to apply `re` to whole group. You can also do it as `r" \1 "`

Comment: I accept this answer because it is the fastest and looks clear.

Comment: I cannot seem to add a second group. for example `pat = re.compile(r"([.!#&][()-_])")`. When I try to use `.sub` with this and say `" \\1" ` or `" \\2 "` now nothing happens. The original string is returned unchanged.

Comment: your problem  is not clear to me. Can you give an example of what you are trying to accomplish.
Or better yet, try using the regex on https://regexr.com/ , this is an excellent site that explains the regex you use, thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

A simple generator expression can be used to accomplish your problem. No need for `re` in your case:

```
>>> string = "hello... (world)!"
>>> ''.join((' {} '.format(el) if el in '.()!' else el for el in string))
'hello .  .  .   ( world )  ! '
>>>
```

This works by the generator looping over every character in `string` and testing if the charterer is "special". If it is, then the character *with* surrounding white space is returned. Otherwise, the current character is simply returned. Then, `''.join()` is used to join the generator object that is returned from the expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `isaplha()`:

```
data = "hello... (world)!"

for c in data[:]:
    if not c.isalpha():
        data = data.replace(c,  " %s " % c)

print(data)
```